# React token based authentication with laravel

Tags: reactjs, authentication, authorization, bearer-token, laravel-sanctum

I am working on a React + Laravel project using Laravel Sanctum for API authentication. When I log in, Laravel Sanctum provides a token that I store in the LocalStorage, and then during every API call I am passing the token in the header to fetch data from the server as the authenticated user.

I am trying to not to show the login page to the already logged-in users.

The way I am doing this right now it by sending the token to the backend to check if the user is authorized or not, but it takes time to get response from the server. So when I hit the login route it shows me the login page first then when response comes back, it redirects me to the home page or another page. That is the thing I am trying to avoid.

Is there a way can I prevent unauthorized users to go to the authorized page as soon as I hit the route?

Comment: Can you share what library are you using for the routing? 
Also a good starting point would be to explore how JWT works and what you can store in it to avoid those additional checks to the server with each page load or request.

Comment: thnx @NikolaMilutinovic for replying. I am using "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0" and I am using laravel sanctum for authentication. That why I had to check user authorization  by sending API to the server rather than just pick token from storage, As u know if u check authentication based on my storage token it won't be valid all the time bcz i can manually set token to storage